# JBOSS core-service access through management console

Tags: jboss

when we try to access core-service in JBOSS through management console we are getting internal error
We access as http://localhost:10090/console/core-service/platform-mbean/type/threading?operation=resource&recursive&proxies&include-runtime&include-defaults.

Regards
Uma S

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: @James, JBOSS version is JBOSS-EAP-6.2

Comment: What does the stack trace look like? There's not much to go on here.